# Droppable not working inside Sortable

Tags: jquery, dynamic, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to get jquery droppable to work inside jquery sortable. The only way that I have been able to get it to work is to destroy the sortable after the droppable is added in the sortable receive.

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/dan2012/vMnQM/

Is there anything that I can change to get the droppable to work inside the sortable? I tried changing tolerance and did not have any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dan2012/DzPX2/ I think that this will have to work.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this simple version does what you want?

```
$(".droppable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        var e = $(this).data().sortable.currentItem;
        $(this).append(e);
    }
});

$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".droppable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});​
```

Try it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vMnQM/2/

Comment: I also want to be able to drop span Drag Me into .section when .section is in .droppable

Comment: oh. I thought that was your mistake.